# Using k-fold cross validation, I found that Model 1 has MAE lower than Model 2 while MSE is the opposite..which model I should select?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, python, cross-validation

Model 1 : MAE = 2.12, MSE= 8.8, R2=0.89
Model 2: MAE=2.17, MSE=8.408, R2=0.9

Which model will be selected?

Comment: Pick the one that is more relevant to the research/analysis question at hand.

Comment: The question is to find the appropriate regression model that can describe the data.

Comment: Yes. And my suggestion is to pick the one (model) that is more relevant to the research/analysis question at hand. A MAE vs MSE comparison is pointless in the absence of context.

Comment: You're asking us to choose your loss function but we aren't mind readers.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, have you checked that these differences are real and not just within the random uncertainty of your performance estimation?

Secondly, model 1 having larger MSE with smaller MAE means that while it predicted most cases better than model 2, in some cases the predictions were noticeably worse: you "bought" smaller error for most cases by "paying" with a few cases being totally wrong.
As others have said, it depends on the application question at hand which compromise (model) is better.

Answer (score 0):

Here are both formulas:

[image]

now lets do an example, we have two values

```
Y1 = 1
Y2 = 2
Y3 = -1
```

and prediction:

```
Y1_hat = 1
Y2_hat = 4
Y3_hat = 1
```

Then MSE and MAE would be:

```
MSE = 1/3 * ((0)+(-2)*(-2)+(-2)*(-2)) = 1/3*8 = 2,64
MAE = 1/3 * ((0)+2+2) = 1/3* 4 = 1,32
```

But as the comments already said, it is your decision...this is just an explanation to make the calculation clear for you